# PartedMagic in vSphere 4 - Weird Mouse Behaviour

Tags: vmware-vsphere, mouse, gparted

Mouse is pointing to a fraction of where it should in a VMware vSphere 4.0 vm with the windows vSphere client.

Booting up UBCD -> PartedMagic... The mouse pointer has x/y co-ordinates of a smaller fraction of that which it "should" have.

This can be seen here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bx2emQ1IpQw

Can anyone work out how I can make the mouse work properly with GParted and vSphere 4?

I know I could probably spend ages learning how to use the command line to do what I need here, but the whole point of using GParted is for the GUI..

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When PartedMagic is selected from the UBCD menu, it shows an options list before it boots, choosing option 4 "Alternative graphical server" will use Xvesa, which is usable.

There's still a quirky mouse issue, but mousing off the screen seems to fix it...

Answer (score 0):

I used the [GParted Live CD](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php) without a problem but have never tried the Ultimate Boot CD version.  Have you try downloading the GParted only live CD?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to install vmware-tools on the guest OS (PartedMagic in this case) ?  I know it includes some graphics accelerators which might help out.  What linux distro is PartedMagic based on?